# Communication fragment-fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have **two fragments**, on one there's a list view and on the other there's a button and an edit text.

I'm trying to clear the edit text when the information is entered on the db when pressing the button, and after that clear the edit text from the same `onClick` method.

Is there any way to have access to an edit text from a different fragment?

Comment: Do fragment to fragment communication through the hosting Activity.  http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html  use callbacks

Comment: Are that two fragments located in the same activity?

Comment: @NikoYuwono Yes, both are on the same activity.

Comment: @IvánMartín check my answer

Comment: @IvánMartín I'm a bit confused here. which one clears the `EditText`? the first or second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first one you need to define an interface

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    OnClickButton mCallback;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnClickButton {
        public void onClickClear();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnClickButton) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnClickButton");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

And then your second fragment

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    private EditText mEditText;

    public void clearEditText() {
        mEditText.setText("");
    }

    ...

}
```

And the last one is to implement the interface from FragmentA in your Activity

```
public static class MyActivity extends Activity
        implements FragmentA.OnClickButton{

    public void onClickClear() {
        FragmentB fragmentB = (FragmentB)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_b);

        if (fragmentB != null) {
            fragmentB.clearEditText();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```